# Графика и анимация в android

Tags: java, android, анимация, графика

Каким образом разработчик может создавать подобные анимации?

Т.е. я представляю, что сначала дизайнер рисует макет и анимации, в своем графическом редакторе. Потом, разработчик как то это должен реализовать. Вот очень интересно, можно ли  с этой задачей справиться с помощью `AnimatedVectorDrawable`?

[image: такие]
<sub>(источник: [cloudfront.net](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/467195/screenshots/1682459/tell_gif.gif))</sub>

[image: такие]
<sub>(источник: [cloudfront.net](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/116693/screenshots/1925873/recipe-finder.gif))</sub>

[image: и такие]

Comment: dribbble'овские анимашки?

Comment: Про кастрюлю с супом как то гайд попадался с детальным разбором, как она делается, но мне искать лень. Он где то там, в интернете лежит.

Comment: @ermak0ff ну не обязательно, вообще подобного рода.

Comment: @pavlofff эта? https://yalantis.com/blog/how-we-built-customizable-pull-to-refresh-pull-to-cook-soup-animation/

Comment: Так в чем вопрос ? Вам необходимо перечислить инструменты которые там используются? можно только догадываться, сейчас любую сложную анимацию можно сделать с помощью векторов, но загрузится поток, поэтому создают группу анимаций, если брать кастрюлю например. В pullToRefresh, потом много обычных анимаций с разными interpolator, овощи и крышка path + interpolator, дальше пузырьки и огонь это frame. Но это только догадки.

Comment: вот спасибо, за VectorDrawableApi, буду юзать.
@ermak0ff спасибо за ссылку, сам не смог нагуглить)

Comment: Я почти угадал)) Но гайд этот поверхностный, в принципе понятно это блог, лайки просмотры и тд, вся работа за ширмой. Пузырьки не frame  сделаны интересно, кстати можно добавить всего одну строчку и смотрелись бы намного реальней, смещение не только по y но и диапазон по x на небольшой интервал, тогда пузырьки смотрелись бы реальней смещаясь ещё влево и вправо)